# How to Output the results of a MySQL query that used aliases?

Tags: php, mysql, echo, alias, self-join

I have two primary MySQL tables (profiles and contacts) with many supplementary tables (prefixed by prm_). They are accessed and manipulated via PHP.

In this instance I am querying the profiles table where I will retrieve an Owner ID and a Breeder ID. This will then be referenced against the contacts table where the information on the Owners and Breeders is kept.

I received great help here on another question regarding joins and aliases, where I was also furnished with the following query. Unfortunately, I am having huge difficulty in actually echoing out the results. Every single site that deals with Self Joins and Aliases provide lovely examples of the queries - but then skip to "and this Outputs etc etc etc". How does it output????

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT *
         FROM profiles
              INNER JOIN prm_breedgender
                  ON profiles.ProfileGenderID = prm_breedgender.BreedGenderID
              LEFT JOIN contacts ownerContact
                  ON profiles.ProfileOwnerID = ownerContact.ContactID
              LEFT JOIN prm_breedcolour
                  ON profiles.ProfileAdultColourID = prm_breedcolour.BreedColourID
              LEFT JOIN prm_breedcolourmodifier
                  ON profiles.ProfileColourModifierID = prm_breedcolourmodifier.BreedColourModifierID
) ilv LEFT JOIN contacts breederContact
     ON ilv.ProfileBreederID = breederContact.ContactID
WHERE ProfileName != 'Unknown'
ORDER BY ilv.ProfileGenderID, ilv.ProfileName ASC $limit
```

Coupled with this is the following PHP:

```
$owner = ($row['ownerContact.ContactFirstName'] . ' ' . $row['ownerContact.ContactLastName']);
$breeder = ($row['breederContact.ContactFirstName'] . ' ' . $row['breederContact.ContactLastName']);
```

All details EXCEPT the contacts (gender, colour, etc.) return fine. The `$owner` and `$breeder` variables are empty.

Any help in settling this for me would be **massively** appreciated.

**EDIT:** My final WORKING query:

```
SELECT ProfileOwnerID, ProfileBreederID, 
        ProfileGenderID, ProfileAdultColourID, ProfileColourModifierID, ProfileYearOfBirth, 
        ProfileYearOfDeath, ProfileLocalRegNumber, ProfileName,
        owner.ContactFirstName AS owner_fname, owner.ContactLastName AS owner_lname,
        breeder.ContactFirstName AS breeder_fname, breeder.ContactLastName AS breeder_lname,
        BreedGender, BreedColour, BreedColourModifier

        FROM profiles
                    LEFT JOIN contacts AS owner
                        ON ProfileOwnerID = owner.ContactID
                    LEFT JOIN contacts AS breeder
                        ON ProfileBreederID = breeder.ContactID
            LEFT JOIN prm_breedgender
                        ON ProfileGenderID = prm_breedgender.BreedGenderID
                    LEFT JOIN prm_breedcolour
                        ON ProfileAdultColourID = prm_breedcolour.BreedColourID
                    LEFT JOIN prm_breedcolourmodifier
                        ON ProfileColourModifierID = prm_breedcolourmodifier.BreedColourModifierID

                  WHERE ProfileName != 'Unknown'
            ORDER BY ProfileGenderID, ProfileName ASC $limit
```

Which I could then output by:

```
$owner = ($row['owner_lname'] . ' - ' . $row['owner_fname']);
```

Many Thanks to All!

Comment: Have you tried a print_r on $row to see how the output comes? I don't think the alias is part of the hash that is spit out. Doing a print_r will tell you exactly how the values are coming out.

Comment: What I was meaning was to look at the hash names on $row not the value. Using print_r($row) will spit out the actual hash names used on the data structure.

Comment: It is actually returning the correct values for the Owner and Breeder... but that's not translating somehow

Comment: If you access them by name ("ContactFirstName"), you get only the "second" (Breeder's) name.

Comment: I wish :P I'm not getting anything at all at the moment. It seems I need to specify aliases for the columns in both Inner and Outer queries, rather than use the * symbol?

Comment: @Eamonn: Exactly! Btw, using outer query doesn't really make sense here. You can get rid of it

Comment: Orly?? well, that simplifies things... Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you're using the `mysql_fetch_array` or the `mysql_fetch_assoc`-functions to get the array from the result-set?

In this case, you can't use

```
$row['ownerContact.ContactFirstName']
```

as the [PHP-Docs read](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php):

> If two or more columns of the result have the same field names, the
>   last column will take precedence. To access the other column(s) of the
>   same name, you must use the numeric index of the column or make an
>   alias for the column. For aliased columns, you cannot access the
>   contents with the original column name.

So, you can either use an `AS` in your SQL-query to set other names for the doubled rows or use the numbered indexes to access them.

---

This could then look like this:

#### Using `AS` in your Query

In your standard SQL-query, the columns in the result-set are named like the columns which their values come from. Sometimes, this can be a problem due to a naming-conflict. Using the `AS`-command in your query, you can rename a column in the result-set:

```
SELECT something AS "something_else"
FROM your_table
```

This will rename the `something`-column to `something_else` (you can leave the `""`-quotes out, but I think it makes it more readable).

#### Using the column-indexes for the array

The other way to go is using the column-index instead of their names. Look at this query:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM some_table
```

The result-set will contain two columns, `0 ==> first_name` and `1 ==> last_name`. You can use this numbers to access the column in your result-set:

```
$row[0] // would be the "first_name"-column
$row[1] // would be the "last_name"-column
```

To be able to use the column-index, you'll need to use `mysql_fetch_row` or the `mysql_fetch_assoc`-function, which offers an associative array, a numeric array, or both ("both" is standard).

Comment: Can u give me an example? I'm trying to get it to work here and its not happening...

Comment: You, Sir, are a scholar and a gentleman! So, if i say `SELECT ProfileOwnerID AS Owner, ProfileBreederID AS Breeder, etc`. what do my LEFT JOIN and echo look like? I just want to be sure before I let you go! :P

Comment: The `AS`-commands are noted in your `SELECT`-condition. So instead of using `SELECT *` you would use `SELECT your_col AS "your_preferred_name"`. This has no effect on your JOINs.

Answer (score 2):

you need to replace the * with the data you need , and the similar ones you have to make aliases too : 
ownerContact.ContactFirstName as owner_ContactFirstName
and
breederContact.ContactFirstName as breeder_ContactFirstName .

like this :

select ownerContact.ContactFirstName as owner_ContactFirstName , breederContact.ContactFirstName as breeder_ContactFirstName from profiles join ownerContact ... etc

in this way you will write :

```
$owner = ($row['owner_ContactFirstName'] . ' ' . $row['owner_ContactLastName']);
$breeder = ($row['breeder_ContactFirstName'] . ' ' . $row['breeder_ContactLastName']);
```

Comment: Okaaaaay - which * do I change however? Both?

Comment: changing the second one should be enough

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify table alias when you access row using php. Accessing it by `$row['ContactFirstName']` would work if you didn't have 2  fields with the same name. In this case whatever `ContactFirstName` appears second overwrites the first.

Change your query to use fields aliases, so you can do `$owner = $row['Owner_ContactFirstName']`.
Another option I'm not 100% sure is to access field by index, not by name(e.g. `$owner=$row[11]`). Even if it works I don't recommend to do so, you will have a lot of troubles if change your query a bit.

Answer (score 0):

On outer select You have only two tables:

```
(inner select) as ilv
contacts as breederContact
```

there is no ownerContact at all

Comment: The ownercontact is in the Inner Join, is it not?