# PHP Mysql Correctly Iterate Over Tables With Alias Names

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following Mysql query:

```
$sql = "select r.brand AS brand, r.name AS name, r.cost AS cost, e.price AS price, d.shipping as shipping 
FROM tab.rawproduct r 
INNER JOIN price e ON r.housecode=e.housecode 
INNER JOIN product d ON e.productid=d.productid  
WHERE r.housecode='$housecode'";
```

The houscode is assigned to a variable which is then passed to the sql statement:

```
<label>Housecode:</label><input class="boxes" type="text" name="housecode" value="<?php echo $housecode; ?>"><br />        

$housecode = $_POST['housecode'];
```

Housecode is submitted through a form with action set to $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]

I am trying to iterate over the results with PHP with the following:

```
$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  { 
    $brand = $row['brand'];     
    $housecode  = $row['housecode'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $cost = $row['cost'];
    $salesprice = $row['price'];
    $shipraw = $row['shipping'];
    }
} else {
echo "0 Results";
}

$con->close();
```

Nothing is getting returned when a user submits a housecode and the "0 Results" is echoed.

I have looked into this problem and read [Lucas Knuth's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934982/how-to-output-the-results-of-a-mysql-query-that-used-aliases):

> If two or more columns of the result have the same field names, the
>   last column will take precedence. To access the other column(s) of the
>   same name, you must use the numeric index of the column or make an
>   alias for the column. For aliased columns, you cannot access the
>   contents with the original column name. So, you can either use an AS
>   in your SQL-query to set other names for the doubled rows or use the
>   numbered indexes to access them.

So I have used the AS keyword in the above query but I still don't get any results.  I have also tried changing to mysqli_fetch_row($result) and tried to assign the $row[0], [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934982/how-to-output-the-results-of-a-mysql-query-that-used-aliases) ... etc instead.  Again no luck.

When I run Apache error_log I get the following:

Trying to get property of non-object on line 34.  On line 34 and 35 I have:

```
if ($result->num_rows >0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  {
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: What's the value of `$housecode` and does it exist in the database?

Comment: And see about prepared statements

Comment: You're aliasing all of your columns, so that wouldn't be an issue. However, you're not passing back the housecode in your results, so `$code  = $row['housecode'];` would fail.

Comment: Housecode is a string "HT0008" for example.  The form works because when I run the query in the command line, data is returned successfully.

Comment: I have updated the question and added more information

Comment: What do you mean by `when I run the query in the command line, data is returned successfully.` ?

Comment: I'm assuming that the value of $sql is set after you set the value of $housecode, otherwise the SQL won't get the right value.  Check by echoing out the SQL before the call to `query`

Comment: Echoing the sql does actually contain the housecode.  When I copy and paste the echoed $sql and paste into Mysql in the terminal, the results are returned.

Comment: `mysqli_num_rows` is a little screwy sometimes. `The behaviour of mysqli_num_rows() depends on whether buffered or unbuffered result sets are being used. For unbuffered result sets, mysqli_num_rows() will not return the correct number of rows until all the rows in the result have been retrieved.`

Comment: Yea, with your last edit I'd say your query failed. `var_dump($result)` should give you the hint.

Comment: Check mysql logs aswell and try to nail down the error  with http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the answer for myself.

The problem was that I was selecting just one database, ie tab.rawproduct BUT tables price e and procduct d are from a totally different database.

So the sql query should have been this:

```
$sql = "SELECT r.brand, r.name, r.cost, e.price, d.shipping FROM 
tab.rawproduct r
INNER JOIN t1.price e on r.housecode=e.housecode
INNER JOIN t1.product d on e.productid=d.productid 
WHERE r.housecode = '$housecode' ";
```

If found the error by checking the mysqli->errno:

```
if(!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
 echo "Error: Our query failed to execute and here is why: \n";
 echo "Query: " . $sql . "\n";
 echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->errno . "\n";
 echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error . "\n";
 exit;
}
```

Hopefully this may help someone else facing the same problem.

Thanks for all your comments and help.

Comment: That's hilarious, getting voted down for following all the rules, asking for help, clearly defining the problem and showing what you've tried.  You are also encouraged to do your own research, which is clearly evident and highlighting an issue which others may find helpful.  Just love how some people are so anonymously unhelpful and de-motivating and offering no constructive points.  Superb.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your example and I found a bug in your select query: you're missing the `r.housecode`.

```
$sql = "select r.brand AS brand, r.name AS name, r.cost AS cost, e.price AS price, d.shipping as shipping, r.housecode AS housecode
FROM tab.rawproduct r 
INNER JOIN price e ON r.housecode=e.housecode 
INNER JOIN product d ON e.productid=d.productid  
WHERE r.housecode='$housecode'";
```

Check if the cross references match in your tables, because in my examples the rows are correctly returned

table `price`:

```
housecode  productid   price
HT0008     4           3400
HT0008     5           5400
```

table `product`:

```
shipping  productid
64        4
78        5
```

table `rawproduct`:

```
brand     name     cost   housecode
Cani      bellaaa  63824  HT0008
```

Comment: That already has been elaborated in comments and besides that it's not the source of the problem.